# Android - Jacoco code coverage ignores Robolectric tests

Tags: java, android, testing, robolectric, jacoco

Trying to get Code coverage on my Robolectric tests in Android utilising Jacoco but it simply refuses to acknowledge my Robolectric tests when creating the reports.

My jacoco.gradle file is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.6.201602180812"
}

project.afterEvaluate {

    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def name = variant.name
        def testTaskName = "test${name.capitalize()}UnitTest"

        tasks.create(name: "${testTaskName}Coverage", type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "$testTaskName") {
            group = "Reporting"
            description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports for the ${name.capitalize()} build."

            classDirectories = fileTree(
                    dir: "${project.buildDir}/intermediates/classes/${name}",
                    excludes: ['**/R.class',
                               '**/R$*.class',
                               '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
                               '**/*$ViewBinder*.*',
                               '**/BuildConfig.*',
                               '**/Manifest*.*']
            )

            sourceDirectories = files(['src/main/java'].plus(android.sourceSets[name].java.srcDirs))
            executionData = files("${project.buildDir}/jacoco/${testTaskName}.exec")

            reports {
                xml.enabled = true
                html.enabled = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this setup I can get Coverage reports but I get 0% coverage despite having Robolectric tests in "src/test/java".

If I add in the following code to that file:

```
android {
    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            jacoco {
                includeNoLocationClasses = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error when Gradle tries to sync:

> Error:No such property: includeNoLocationClasses for class:
>   org.gradle.testing.jacoco.plugins.JacocoTaskExtension_Decorated

I know that I need to have Gradle 2.13 to use this includeNoLocationClasses value so in graddle-wrapper.properties I have the following:

```
#Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions-snapshots/gradle-2.13-20160228000026+0000-all.zip
```

I am pretty certain I am running Gradle 2.13 with Android plugin version 1.5

In my apps Gradle file I have the following:

```
//...

apply from: 'jacoco.gradle'

//..

testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}

//...

debug {
    testCoverageEnabled true
}
```

And the command I use to run the coverage is:

> ./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport

So I am wondering why I get the includeNoLocationClasses error despite using the correct Gradle version? And outside of that maybe I am doing something wrong where Jacoco isn't picking up the Robolectric tests in src/test.java ?

Comment: I noticed that this code is now deprecated (in gradle-android-plugin 3.x): android {
    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            jacoco {
                includeNoLocationClasses = true
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: Donal, a little help. While I'm trying to execute configure you mentioned I'm getting. **"Error:Could not get unknown property 'android' for root project 'MyProject' of type org.gradle.api.Project."** Any idea why !!

Comment: Sorry @CoDe I can't remember, and the code I was working on for this has been shelved. If I can recall I'll let you know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see you `build.gradle` completely, but to have that flag in you have to:

1. Use **gradle** `2.13+`
2. Use **jacoco** `0.7.6.201602180812`

You're sure that you use **gradle** proper version. So, I think, the issue is only in using wrong **jacoco**.

Mentioning `jacoco {toolVersion = "0.7.6.201602180812"}` doesn't influence **gradle** DSL. You should add newer **jacoco** plugin:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:...'
    }
}
```

And you should apply plugin, which you're already doing:

```
apply from: 'jacoco'
```

After such configuraiton you don't need `jacoco {toolVersion = "..."}` more.

Note: consider to update to newer **android gradle** plugin, `2.2.x` is already stable. **jacoco** also has newer version already `0.7.7.201606060606`

One more note: if you see original issue in Android Studio, check that you use wrapper by default and check that you pointed wrapper to gradle 2.13

Comment: Thanks, I was not using the Gradle 2.13 wrapper by default, changing that removed the Jacoco error, however when I run the command to get the test coverage Jacoco is still not picking up my Robolectric tests and is reporting 0% coverage despite tests existing for the classes.

Comment: Can you run it with `--debug` or `--info`? It might skip if it can not find exec file. So check your paths carefully

Comment: When I add --info to the command I am seeing this - Executing task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest' (up-to-date check took 0.0 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
No tests found, nothing to do.
But I think the "connected" means it's looking in androidTest for instrumentation tests? I dont have any of those yet, just Robolectric unit tests in app/src/test/java , each test is run with my TestRunner that extends RobolectricGradleTestRunner and each test annotated with @Test - there must be some reason Jacoco is not picking up the tests?

Comment: Can you run `./gradlew tasks` and see what exactly tasks do you have? Also, you call `createDebugCoverageReport` (at least from question), however, your coverage task named as `test${variantname}Coverage`

Comment: Well thats embarrassing! I was mixing two tutorials together and completely got focused on using the createDebugCoverageReport one tutorial recommended and forgot I was creating variant tasks, it's working now, many many thanks for your help.

Comment: `apply from: 'jacoco.gradle'` doesn't work. Needs to be: `apply from: 'jacoco'`

Comment: Check the question. He extracted all jacoco gradle code to `jacoco.gradle`.