# Gradle sync issue after updating Studio version to 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Recently I upgraded my Android Studio version from 2.2 to 2.3. But my project which was working fine in 2.2 giving below error in 2.3 while gradle sync

```
Error:No such property: includeNoLocationClasses for class: org.gradle.testing.jacoco.plugins.JacocoTaskExtension_Decorated
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031358/android-jacoco-code-coverage-ignores-robolectric-tests

Comment: Still post your gradle files, let see how it goes!